# Show that the probability of two pairs in poker is approximately 0.048.

Tags: probability

My problem is counting the number of ways in which a pair can occur. The answer in the back says
$${13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}44.$$
I get $${13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}48.$$

I don't understand where the 44 comes from? The 48 = 52-4 comes from not selecting the 4 cards that we obtained. If someone could just explain where the 44 comes from that would be great.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "two pairs". Does the hand "55666" count as two pairs? Or is it a full house?

Comment: Would it be easier written ${13 \choose 2}{11\choose 1} \times {4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}$?  The $44$ is ${52-8 \choose 1}$ or ${13-2\choose 1}\times{4 \choose 1}$ to select the card whose value appears once after  two values (i.e. eight cards) are not possible as these values have been selected for the two pairs

Comment: $4$ of your $48$ remaining cards would lead to a full-house rather than two pairs

Comment: Keep in mind that in standard Poker terminology, saying that a hand is of type X precludes all stronger types.  Thus $XXXYY$ is not two pairs just as $XXXYZ$ is not one pair.

Comment: Would it be easier written....? yes that makes perfect sense